# OllyDbg plugins not working

Tags: ollydbg

I am using OllyDbg **2.1.0.4** and I cant get any plugins to work. I have tried ODbgScript.1.82, OllyDump v2.1.0.2 and Advanced Labels v1.3.0.9.

When I tried the first two I got Plugins tab greyed out. Advanced Labels makes OllyDbg crash.

I have set the plugin path to ..\OllyDbg 2.01\Plugins in the .ini file.

What is there that I am missing?

Answer (score 1):

I believe all of those plugins are for [OllyDbg v1](http://www.ollydbg.de/odbg110.zip) only, not v2.

If you absolutely need to use them, you can downgrade to [OllyDbg v1](http://www.ollydbg.de/odbg110.zip).

If the plugin source code is available (or if you want to reverse engineer the plugin binaries and rewrite their code from scratch), you could try to rebuild them using [the v2 plugin SDK](http://www.ollydbg.de/Help/Main.htm) (sample plugins [here](http://www.ollydbg.de/plug201h.zip)).

Comment: I found them on tuts4you in the category OllyDbg 2, What is your source? Or am I left with disassembling the plugin and looking at the  binary to determine whether it uses Olly API for 1.10 or for 2.01?